# Проектирование php

Tags: php, проектирование

Доброго времени суток. Не могли бы вы подсказать какую-нибудь литературу по теории проектирования в целом? Хотелось бы, чтобы в ней доступным языком объяснялось, к примеру, что такое MVC и зачем это нужно, с чем едят шаблоны проектирования, с чего начинать проектирование и прочее.
Нет, не надо мне объяснять это все в теме - лучше киньте ссылку. =)
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: если понимаете как строить алгоритмы в голове то сами для себя придумаете систему проектирования а если нет то поверьте - никакие книги не помогут ибо будете тупо мыслить шаблонами и ни на шаг не сможете отойти от них. в результате ничего своего не придумаете

Comment: Это вы Лингу говорите? =))

Он просто не хочет изобретать велосипед, когда тот уже изобретен.

Comment: а при чем тут изобретать или нет. теория проектирования это и есть в первую очередь понимание задачи + построение алгоритма и дальнейшая его разработка.

Comment: Для конкретных задач есть конкретные пути решения, которые не только способствуют организации кода, но и облегчают взаимопонимание между программистами. Если следовать вашей логике, человек, которому объяснили, что автомобиль быстрее велосипеда(того самого), сразу подумает, что ролики быстрее автомобиля. Логично же: два колеса->четыре->восемь.

Comment: Нет, мне это нужно скорее для того, чтобы понимать других программистов и разговаривать с ними на одном языке. Заодно это может мне помочь в разработке сложных систем. Мне скорее интересен принцип проектирования, чтобы было удобно и мне, и тому, кто читает мой код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не заморачиваться на PHP, то могу посоветовать:

- [Эрик Дж. Брауде. Технология разработки программного обеспечения](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1605279/). В этом манускрипте детально охвачен весь цикл разработки и сопутствующая бюрократия (её бы студентам в институтах давать, как чудесен был бы мир...)
- [Джим Арлоу, Айла Нейштадт. UML 2 и Унифицированный процесс. Практический объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3631764/). Эта книга сфокусирована конкретно на UML и методологии UP.

Кроме того довелось листать [Leszek A. Maciaszek. Requirements Analysis and System Design](http://www.amazon.com/Requirements-Analysis-System-Design-Maciaszek/dp/0321440366/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1330688370&sr=8-1). Произвела хорошее впечатление.

---

Еще факультативно можно [Beautiful Architecture](http://www.amazon.com/Beautiful-Architecture-Leading-Thinkers-Software/dp/059651798X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1330688796&sr=1-1) почитать. О внутренностях различных крупных проектов, и почему было сделано именно так.

Answer (score 0):

"Совершенный код" Стива Макконнелла

Answer (score 0):

Могу порекомендовать [Совершенный код](http://www.piter.com/collection/starye-tovary/product/sovershennyy-kod) про кодинг в целом 
и [Приемы объектно-ориентированного проектирования](http://www.piter.com/collection/starye-tovary/product/priemy-obektno-orientirovannogo-proektirovaniya) конкретно по шаблонам.